# Calculate grand total when table is filtered

Tags: business-objects, webi

I have a Web Intelligence cross tab report where I show time as columns, customer names as the rows and volume as the measure.

I have applied a ranking to show only the top X along with a (sub-)total, however I want to add a row at the bottom to show the total for all customers for that month.

I had expected to achieve this by using `[Volume] ForAll ([Customer Name])` but that repeats the sub-total, as did `[Volume] ForAll ([Customer Name]))` (in case it was me getting the parentheses wrong).

Am clearly missing something fundamental here which is probably obvious once learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially your ranking is a filter although it doesn't show up that way. If you create a variable with the **NoFilter()** function you should have what you seek.

```
[MonthTotal]=NoFilter([Volume])
```

This is how it looks for me using the eFashion universe...

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you. Need to play around with it as I also have some calculated variables which are giving me #MULTIVALUE errors which I suspect are because the formulas aren't properly defined as SUMs or similar.

Comment: For some reason can't add a line break. Hmm. Second issue is some conditional formatting just isn't working, which is very perplexing when it's showing the right value!